# C# EF6 | The problem of reserving an identity without adding a row in case an exception occurred in data entry

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, identity

I have an identity problem An exception occurred while entering data into the table And suddenly he records an identity every time an exception occurs

Example:

Before insert data:

[image: 1,2 identity]

after intentional any exception:
[image: exception]

I entered correct data after the last error occurred
He added the row with an unordered identity
Identity 3 is missing

[image: 1,2,4]

```
public async Task<T?> CreateAsync(T entity)
        {
            using RetailDbContext context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext();
            EntityEntry<T> createResult = await context.Set<T>().AddAsync(entity);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return createResult.Entity;
        }
```

insert unordered identity

Comment: What's the actual problem? Why is it an issue that 3 is missing? Your records all still have unique IDs, which is the point. What's the problem?

Comment: Why do you care? Identity columns are surrogate keys; they have no intrinsic meaning. Gaps happen. If your design can't tolerate gaps, you need to rethink your design.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Just ask is there a solution to the gaps issue, however
It redirected my thinking why I care about gaps if each class has a different id

Comment: It's not an issue so it needs no solution. An identity provides unique, efficient, auto-generated IDs. The fact that they are sequential is just a quirk of the method used to generate them and not the point. If you have a specific need for sequential IDs then don't use an identity in the first place. Many people get concerned about this because it doesn't "feel" right but there's no actual issue.